# Why forEach skips empty elements created by trailing commas in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, trailing

I was reading [Trailing commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas) and [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#sparseArray) documentations on **MDN** meanwhile playing with arrays.

So let's imagine a scenario when you have an array with elements like `Number`, `undefined` and created ones with trailing commas and running a `forEach()` on that. See from the documentation:

> `forEach()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized.

Based on that it skips the elements created with trailing commas but not the `undefined` ones:

```js
const array = [ 1, 2, , 4, , undefined, ];
console.log({ length: array.length }); // shows 6

array.forEach((e, i) => console.log({e, i})); // logging 4 elements
```

In the same time using traditional `for` loop it logs all the elements as expected:

```js
const array = [ 1, 2, , 4, , undefined, ];
console.log({ length: array.length }); // shows 6 as before

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log({e: array[i], i}); // logs 6 elements
}
```

Also **Chrome** developer tool is showing *empty* items for the array for ones created by trailing commas:

[image: chrome-screenshot]

**My questions:**

From the documentation I found `.forEach()` is skipping deleted or uninitialized elements when iterating. So I see that statement, that's how it has been built.

So my questions would be:

1. What's the difference between the `undefined` directly added to the array and by the trailing commas?
2. Why `.forEach()` is showing up one `undefined` which has been added but not all the other ones.
3. How can you differentiate from items called *empty* and `undefined` in this term?

What is going on under the hood? Can someone enlighten me about this scenario?

Appreciate the clarification, thank you!

---

**Update:**

I think I understood after further reading based on the linked questions.

So I took a look how `.forEach()` has been implemented which has an extra check with [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for each elements and that's the difference. See as the following:

```js
const array = [ 1, 2, , 4, , undefined, ];
console.log({ length: array.length }); // shows 6 as before

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log({e: array[i], i, has: i in array});
}
```

So for the directly added `undefined` element the `i in array` returns `true` for all the empty elements `false` which makes sense now. As a result `.forEach` only calls the callback once the current element is existing.

Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: Setting something to `undefined` is still setting it--you initialized it w/ `undefined`. "Under the hood" it knows which elements you've defined.

Comment: You're initializing the item with `undefined`, but if you leave an `empty space` you know an item must be there, but it wasn't initialized, it has no `value/type` so it's skipped on `.forEach()`.

Comment: Notice that a *trailing* comma is just ignored, as if you never had written it. A comma that creates an elision is never a trailing comma.

Comment: Arrays are sparse, the "empty" elements don't exist. Run this: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(array)`.

Comment: @terrymorse arrays *can be* sparse. Not all arrays are, though.

Comment: @VLAZ Fair enough, I'll restate: the array in *this*  example is sparse.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, it makes sense now, just extended my question with my understanding for the scenario with `in` operator. Thanks again!